# How to use Group By after Naturally Joining Multiple Tables

Tags: database, postgresql, select

This is a homework question.

I have a table teams:

```
teamid | teamcity | name
```

A table games:

```
gameid | date | gamecity
```

And a table games_played

```
gameid | teamid | teamscore
```

What I'm trying to do is select only the games that are played where neither team's city is from the city the game is played in.

For instance, if the Toronto Raptors and the Chicago Bulls played a game in New York, that would be selected.

I've tried it a few different ways including:

```
WITH TEMP as (SELECT * FROM GAME NATURAL JOIN 
GAME_PLAYED NATURAL JOIN TEAM WHERE teamcity != gamecity) 
SELECT gameid, gamecity, teamcity, teamname, teamscore FROM TEMP GROUP BY 
gameid, gameid HAVING COUNT(gameid) > 1;
```

and:

```
SELECT gameid, gamecity, teamcity, teamname, teamscore FROM GAME 
NATURAL JOIN GAME_PLAYED NATURAL JOIN TEAM WHERE teamcity != gamecity
GROUP BY gameid HAVING COUNT(gameid) > 1;
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here. The last one gives me an error: "column "teams.teamcity" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out:

```
SELECT gameid, gamecity, teamcity, teamname, teamscore FROM GAME_PLAYED 
NATURAL JOIN GAME NATURAL JOIN TEAM WHERE gameid IN
(SELECT gameid FROM GAME NATURAL JOIN GAME_PLAYED NATURAL JOIN TEAM 
WHERE teamcity != gamecity GROUP BY gameid, gameid HAVING COUNT(gameid) 
> 1) ORDER BY gameid;
```

Comment: you can accept this answer, this let's other know it is solved. thanks. *You might want to learn how to use inner join by the way, natural joins are very limiting.*

Comment: @Used_By_Already It won't let me accept the answer for two days. And thanks, I'll definitely look into inner joins!